# Selenium and Node.JS ElementNotFoundError or NoSuchElementError

Tags: javascript, selenium

I'm trying to find a way to take a screenshot (which I have the method created for) any time there's an 'ElementNotFoundError' without having to define it everywhere in the script (eg, each time I search for an element via ".then(driver.findElement(By.id()).click())", I don't have to always specify to take a screenshot in the 'catch'.

Here's a typical ElementNotFound error:

```
/Users/nhyland/Documents/www/Selenium/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/async/nexttick.js:41
goog.global.setTimeout(function() { throw exception; }, 0);
^
NoSuchElementError: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"loginID"}
at new bot.Error (/Users/nhyland/Documents/www/Selenium/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:108:18)
at Object.bot.response.checkResponse (/Users/nhyland/Documents/www/Selenium/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/response.js:109:9)
at /Users/nhyland/Documents/www/Selenium/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:379:20
at promise.Promise.goog.defineClass.invokeCallback_ (/Users/nhyland/Documents/www/Selenium/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:1337:14)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.. here is the code I created:

```
webdriver.promise.controlFlow().on('uncaughtException', e => {
    console.error('Unhandled error. Taking screenshot.');
    console.log(util.inspect(e.message));
    if(e.name) {
        TakeScreenshot(driver, './Screenshots/'+ e.name);
    } else {
        TakeScreenshot(driver, './Screenshots/UncaughtNoState');
    }
});
```